# Using Axis1 over https

Tags: java, web-services, https, wsdl, axis

how are you?

Well, the problem is that we are using Axis1 to consume a wsdl based webservice which works fine when the URL where the WSDL is located uses plain old HTTP connection, but when it uses a SSL secured conection it brings a ConnectionException when Axis1 tries to download the WSDL document content.

Even reading comments on XMLUtils.class the Axis developers aren't even sure if it will work with HTTPS as it reads on line 810.

Is there any way to solve this? Whe tried to install the certificates on the computer, on ...jre7/lib/security/cacerts and tried to trust all certificates but the problem persists...

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

You can reproduce the Exception with this code:

```
InputSource source = new InputSource(urlWSDL);
DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = (Document) db.parse(source);
```

The Exception is:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DTDConfiguration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Yes it should work for https. Provide further details on the exception you are getting.

Comment: I've tried to reproduce the point where it happens and... I've got it! 

I'll edit the question.

Comment: HTTP uses port 80 by default, HTTPS uses port 443. I get a feeling the server does not actually support HTTPS or is using a different port.

Comment: I don't know, I can connect to the WSDL using SoapUI and pasting the URL to the browser, but if I ping the host I don't get response. So I don't know.

Comment: Pinging is generally not a good way to test a host, it's better to telnet a specific port like 443. Make sure the URL you are putting in SoapUI is the exact same as the one you are using in java. Show some more code perhaps. Is the page slow in the browser? Perhaps your connection timeout is configured too low in java. Run wireshark to see what is actually happening on the wire...

Comment: I've used telnet on the IP and port and can't connect.

Comment: Then either it's a firewall issue (is the browser test run from the same machine?), a DNS issue or a configuration issue.

Comment: WireShark is telling that I'm sendig a SYN packet from port 64180 to their IP and 443 port.
Then, I'm sending two more packages (TCP Retransmission) from the same port to the same IP and port. 
But there's no response from the host.
Maybe they're blocking connections from some ports? Maybe it's because we are behind a proxy? But the proxy has been unlocked for some previous https works...

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the Company Proxy, so I've appended:

```
System.setProperty("https.proxySet", "true");
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", this.getConfiguracionProxy().getUrlProxy());
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", this.getConfiguracionProxy().getPuertoProxy());
```

To:

```
System.setProperty("http.proxySet", "true");
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", this.getConfiguracionProxy().getUrlProxy());
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", this.getConfiguracionProxy().getPuertoProxy());
```

I've found the solution looking at Wireshark. When I was getting the file on SoapUI or on a web browser, the IP was other than the IP used by our application (the true IP). Then I realized that I was behind a proxy.

I've never used Wireshark... I've learned a lot, which is a good thing.

This sets as a System property the stored proxy configuration.

Thanks everybody.